# XSLT: how correctly apply css class in html result

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I have this html that I want to render in a page using an XSLT transformation.

```
<div class="heading" id="allestimenti">
    <h2 class="heading__title">Allestimenti e destinazioni d'uso</h2>
    <div class="heading__subtitle">Un Daily: <span style="color: #3466cd;">infinite soluzioni</span>
</div>
```

I want to render correctly the content between the span tags but what I obtain is

```
Un Daily: <span style="color: #3466cd;">infinite soluzioni</span>
```

as a result. So I want to have the css class correctly applied on the text between the span tags and I want to exclude the span tags too from the rendered result. How can I do it? The part of xsl file I use is

```
<div class="heading__subtitle">
    <xsl:value-of select="Elemento/@Description" />
</div>
```

where the element "Description" will contain exactly

```
Un Daily: <span style="color: #3466cd;">infinite soluzioni</span>
```

Comment: Why not use a dom parser?

Comment: An how do you plan to assign css to plain text  not in a tag?

Comment: @mplungjan the question is that I want the span and css class correctly applied but what I obtain is the text with the span tags and the css specification inside them. And I don't know why the browser doesn't render the html correctly. Maybe I don't use the correct xslt specification, I don't know.

Comment: I do not see the difference between what you obtain and what you want

Answer (score 0):

`<xsl:value-of select="Elemento/@Description" />` suggests you create a text node with the string value of the `Description` attribute of an element node named `Elemento`.

Even if the attribute contains HTML markup that way you don't create any HTML result elements (like a `span` element) but a text node that contains the markup.

If supported by your XSLT processor and setup you can try

```
<xsl:value-of select="Elemento/@Description" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

But that is an optional serialization feature that is for sure not supported for instance by Firefox/Mozilla browsers or in other uses of XSLT where the XSLT processor does not serialize or is not in charge of the serialization.

Comment: thanks a lot! It's exactly what I'm searching for. I tried to use this solution in Mozilla/Firefox too and everything works.